# JsonDecoder decode array with same key comes as different datatype in swift

Tags: swift

```
 let responseData = try JSONDecoder().decode(MenuResponseModel, from: jsonData!)


struct MenuResponseModel : Codable {
  let ratingAverage : Double?
  let ratingcount : Int?
}
```

Sample Response:

```
[{
"ratingAverage": 3,
"reviewCount": 100,
},{
"ratingAverage": 4.2,
"reviewCount": 10,
}]
```

ratingAverage ==> Some times it's coming as "Double" or "Int"

Can some one suggested me, how can I do that by using Codable approach?

Comment: Decode always `Double`, it accepts also `Int` values.

Comment: But, it's not accepting.

Comment: `Double.self` does decode `Int` values, could it be that the value is `String` (wrapped in double quotes)?

Comment: Can you please share me some sample code @vadian

Comment: No, *can **you** please share some* more information for example the JSON of both cases.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comments `Double` considers both `Int` and floating point values.

There are two major issues:

1. You have to decode an array `[MenuResponseModel]`
2. The key `reviewCount` doesn't match the struct member `ratingcount`

---

This decodes the JSON correctly

```
let jsonString = """
[{"ratingAverage": 3,"reviewCount": 100},
 {"ratingAverage": 4.2,"reviewCount": 10}
]
"""

struct MenuResponseModel : Codable {
  let ratingAverage : Double
  let reviewCount : Int
}

let data = Data(jsonString.utf8)

do {
    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode([MenuResponseModel].self, from: data)
    print(result)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```